# How to work with Scala and Jcurses?

Tags: scala, jcurses

I want to use  Jcurses with Scala on a 64-bit Ubuntu.
Unfortunately i didn't find any tutorial about this subject. Can anybody help me!

My test program "testjcurses.scala"

```
import jcurses.system._
object TestJcurses {
  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    println("okay")
    Toolkit.init()
    }
  }
```

I processed it the following way:

```
fsc -cp ~/software/Java/jcurses/lib/jcurses.jar:~/software/Java/jcurses/src -d . -Djava.library.path=~/software/Java/jcurses/lib testjcurses.scala 
scala -cp ~/software/Java/jcurses/lib/jcurses.jar:~/software/Java/jcurses/src:.  -Djava.library.path=~/software/Java/jcurses/lib  TestJcurses
```

The result is:

```
okay
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jcurses.system.Toolkit.getLibraryPath(Toolkit.java:97)
    at jcurses.system.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:37)
    at TestJcurses$.main(testjcurses.scala:9)
    at TestJcurses.main(testjcurses.scala)
   ..........
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What happens if you do the same thing in Java?

Comment: I used java long time ago. It will take some time to perform this task.

Comment: By the way, your sample code runs fine on my machine—although it took some effor to fix the JCurses makefile to build on OS X. There's just something wrong with your setup.

Comment: with java the Program works fine.

Comment: JCurses is likely not finding the library, since the stack trace shows a failure in `getLibraryPath`. Below my best guess.

Comment: @pommfritz: if you like the answer, could you please also upvote it? Thanks.

Comment: @Blaisorblade: I'm sorry I don't have the required  reputation yet to do so.

Comment: @pommfritz: ah sorry, I had forgot that's a privilege!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use `~` in bash like that — `~` is expanded to your home dir only right after an (unquoted) space (technically, at the beginning of a bash word, but "after a space" is the simple version). Look how your command line is expanded:

```
$ echo scala -cp ~/software/Java/jcurses/lib/jcurses.jar:~/software/Java/jcurses/src:.  -Djava.library.path=~/software/Java/jcurses/lib  TestJcurses
scala -cp /Users/pgiarrusso/software/Java/jcurses/lib/jcurses.jar:~/software/Java/jcurses/src:. -Djava.library.path=~/software/Java/jcurses/lib TestJcurses
```

As you can see, the `~` is there in the expanded version, and will arrive unchanged to your program, which will be unable to interpret it as anything since tilde expansion is a job for the shell.

Also, you shouldn't need the source directory `~/software/Java/jcurses/src` in your classpath (since source files aren't needed to run the program). So try:

```
scala -cp ~/software/Java/jcurses/lib/jcurses.jar:. -Djava.library.path=$HOME/software/Java/jcurses/lib  TestJcurses
```